# Purpose of implementing vtable in C instead of using C++

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I've just started to dive into GStreamer framework and I discovered with quite surprise that despite the fact it written in pure C it uses objects and polymorphism. Then I discovered that it's possible to emulate some of C++ features like inheritance in C. It's about implementing a virtual functions table by ourselves. I'm a little bit confused about this idea why would someone need it. If I had to choose between implementing virtual tables in C and use C++ for the project I would definitely use tested and well known implementation of C++ language features. The whole idea seems to me like reinventing the wheel. What are advantages of having macros like in C:

```
GST_IS_EVENT(obj)
GST_EVENT_CAST(obj)
```

over in C++:

```
dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&baseObj);
```

There are two things that I can think of:

- C is understand relatively good by more people and it's easier to maintain codebase with more number contributors
- C is simpler and code will be easier to maintain

Are there any technical advantages of C with implementing vtable over C++?

Comment: Why is it surprising that you can write object oriented code in C? The Linux kernel does this all the time. Just because your language doesn't give you tools to make something convenient does not mean it makes it impossible. In the end, *anything* can be implemented in assembly.

Comment: One of the reason, that could be a must when you are producing libraries or other pieces of code to be shared with other external code, is that the memory management and other dynamic functions behind C++ implementation can be inconsistent and even conflicting on code coming from different compilers.  Writing everything on pure plain C make effective the implementation of every type and mixing almost any language and compiler.

Comment: Consider the age of that library too. C++ compilers/ecosystems wasn't what it is today in 1999.

Comment: If you are writing a library that you want `C` programmers to be able to use then you can't use `C++` polymorphism.

Comment: Re: "it's possible to emulate some of C++ features like inheritance in C" -- back in the olden days, C++ was compiled by cfront, which produced C code which was then compiled by the C compiler.

Comment: "object oriented code in C? The Linux kernel does this all the time. " That the linux kernel was started in C is also surprising to me... Seeing all the hacks and macros to get only a minimum of "comfort" looks horrible. Especially there are different "object ideas" in use in parallel. And the comments from Linus to C++ is more than surprising... :-)

Comment: @Galik: Not entirely true: You can write the library in C++ and provide a C API. Only if use of the library necessarily involves inheriting from provided classes or using templates, this doesn't work. I don't know if this is the case with gstreamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important reason is, that C library ABI is also the standard library ABI at least on Linux and Windows and Mac. In other words, these libraries can be used from any language (which supports using external libraries).

C++ is different story. For example, there is no standard ABI for C++ vtable. Also, to support methods and function overloading and name spaces, C++ does name mangling for symbols. And then exceptions are yet another thing which affects how functions are called, and that may even need specific compiler switches even if using the same compiler.

It would be possible to just write "C" with C++, and export only `extern "C"` symbols, but if you do that, you might as well use C to avoid complexity of mixing languages.

Answer (score -3):

Probably because C++ offers many more features than they need for their project.

Maybe their OOP model is not the same as what C++ provides.